# Not refreshing content pagination on search result

Tags: pagination, search

I am trying to create custom search on my website and everything goes okay except one problem - no refresh content on pagination.

Here is what i am doing.

My searchform:

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

<h3><?php _e( 'Search', 'bmpl' ); ?></h3>

<input type="hidden" name="search" value="advanced">

<label for="name"><?php _e( 'Keyword: ', 'bmpl' ); ?></label><br>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Keyword:', 'bmpl' ); ?>" name="name" id="name" />

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Go" />
```

Here is sample function in functions to load custom search result on specific template

```
function wpse_load_custom_search_template(){
if( isset($_REQUEST['search']) == 'advanced' ) {
    require('advanced-search-result.php');
    die();
}}add_action('init','wpse_load_custom_search_template');
```

And now the last - search result template

```
<div class="main-content-wrap" style="color:white;">

    <div class="info-content clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">

            <?php                 

            $_name = $_GET['name'] != '' ? $_GET['name'] : '';
            $current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                    's'             =>  $_name, 
                    'posts_per_page' => 6,
                    'paged'          => $current_page
                );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
            <?php if ($wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-ts-12">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                        <div class="news-item-card">
                            <div class="news-item-img" >
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <?php kama_pagenavi('', '', true, array(), $wp_query); ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?> 
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="not_found">Nothing found<a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>"> Home</a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>     

</div>
```

Kama pagenavi - function for pagination, works fine on all not-search pages on the same site, where search should work.
Code of pagination function:

function kama_pagenavi( $before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $args = array(), $wp_query = null ) {  if( ! $wp_query ){
        wp_reset_query();
        global $wp_query;
    }

```
$default_args = array(
    'text_num_page'   => '',
    'num_pages'       => 10,
    'step_link'       => 10, 
    'dotright_text'   => '…',
    'dotright_text2'  => '…', 
    'back_text'       => '« back', 
    'next_text'       => 'next»', 
    'first_page_text' => '« start', 
    'last_page_text'  => 'end»', 

$default_args = apply_filters('kama_pagenavi_args', $default_args );

$args = array_merge( $default_args, $args );

extract( $args );

$posts_per_page = (int) $wp_query->get('posts_per_page');
$paged          = (int) $wp_query->get('paged');
$max_page       = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

if( $max_page <= 1 )
    return false;

if( empty( $paged ) || $paged == 0 )
    $paged = 1;

$pages_to_show = intval( $num_pages );
$pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show-1;

$half_page_start = floor( $pages_to_show_minus_1/2 );
$half_page_end = ceil( $pages_to_show_minus_1/2 ); 

$start_page = $paged - $half_page_start; 
$end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;

if( $start_page <= 0 )
    $start_page = 1;
if( ($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1 )
    $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
if( $end_page > $max_page ) {
    $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
    $end_page = (int) $max_page;
}

if( $start_page <= 0 )
    $start_page = 1;
$out = '';
$link_base = str_replace( 99999999, '___', get_pagenum_link( 99999999 ) );
$first_url = get_pagenum_link( 1 );
if( false === strpos( $first_url, '?') )
    $first_url = user_trailingslashit( $first_url );

$out .= $before . "<div class='wp-pagenavi'>\n";

    if( $text_num_page ){
        $text_num_page = preg_replace( '!{current}|{last}!', '%s', $text_num_page );
        $out.= sprintf( "<span class='pages'>$text_num_page</span> ", $paged, $max_page );
    }
    if ( $back_text && $paged != 1 )
        $out .= '<a class="prev" href="'. ( ($paged-1)==1 ? $first_url : str_replace( '___', ($paged-1), $link_base ) ) .'">'. $back_text .'</a> ';
    if ( $start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page ) {
        $out.= '<a class="first" href="'. $first_url .'">'. ( $first_page_text ? $first_page_text : 1 ) .'</a> ';
        if( $dotright_text && $start_page != 2 ) $out .= '<span class="extend">'. $dotright_text .'</span> ';
    }
    for( $i = $start_page; $i <= $end_page; $i++ ) {
        if( $i == $paged )
            $out .= '<span class="current">'.$i.'</span> ';
        elseif( $i == 1 )
            $out .= '<a href="'. $first_url .'">1</a> ';
        else
            $out .= '<a href="'. str_replace( '___', $i, $link_base ) .'">'. $i .'</a> ';
    }
    $dd = 0;
    if ( $step_link && $end_page < $max_page ){
        for( $i = $end_page+1; $i<=$max_page; $i++ ) {
            if( $i % $step_link == 0 && $i !== $num_pages ) {
                if ( ++$dd == 1 )
                    $out.= '<span class="extend">'. $dotright_text2 .'</span> ';
                $out.= '<a href="'. str_replace( '___', $i, $link_base ) .'">'. $i .'</a> ';
            }
        }
    }
    // в конец
    if ( $end_page < $max_page ) {
        if( $dotright_text && $end_page != ($max_page-1) )
            $out.= '<span class="extend">'. $dotright_text2 .'</span> ';
        $out.= '<a class="last" href="'. str_replace( '___', $max_page, $link_base ) .'">'. ( $last_page_text ? $last_page_text : $max_page ) .'</a> ';
    }
    // вперед
    if ( $next_text && $paged != $end_page )
        $out.= '<a class="next" href="'. str_replace( '___', ($paged+1), $link_base ) .'">'. $next_text .'</a> ';

$out .= "</div>". $after ."\n";

$out = apply_filters('kama_pagenavi', $out );

if( $echo )
    return print $out;

return $out;
```

}

But even if use something simple, like next\prev links - still no fine working.

Hope someone can help me, because this issue is driving me crazy on 3rd site in a row, can not understand what is going wrong and problem slowly moves me to insanity.

Sorry for big length and bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed architecture and code a while. 
Simplified example:

normal form, for example with search keyword inside some templete.

```
<form method="get" id="search_form" action="/results">
 <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text_input" placeholder="Type something for search">
 <button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```

After that i create results.php
Here is code:

```
 <?php /* Template name: Custom Search */ 
  get_header(); 
 ?>
 <?php 
  if($_GET['search_text'] && !empty($_GET['search_text']) ) 
   {
    $text = $_GET['search_text'];
   }
  ?>
<div class="wrap" style="color:white;">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php
            $big = 999999999; 
            $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                's' => $text,
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'paged' => $paged,
            );
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
            <?php if ($my_query->have_posts()): ?>
            <?php while($my_query -> have_posts()) : $my_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
            echo paginate_links( array(
                            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                            'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
                            ) );
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Nothing to show u, human.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

After form i create new page in admin dashboard, called "Search results" with "results" slug with template "Advanced Search" from previously created results.php. And that`s all. More custom field can be easily added, and if needed to someone i can post way to do this here.